# Blazor page stuck on Firefox

Tags: .net, firefox, iis, ssl-certificate, blazor-server-side

I have a strange problem. My Blazor server side page works without any problem on Chrome and Edge but with Firefox it gets stuck right at the beginning. I cant figure it out what to do. The problem started to appear when we configured our IIS to use SSL (https). With http it worked without any problems.

Does anyone has similar problem and maybe a solution?

In the link below is the screenshot of the error from the Firefox console

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuKmV.png)

Comment: try to add the error as text not image.

Comment: I see the error code in your screenshot is 400, you can try to use FRT to see details about the 400 error, this will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules